# How to mock this in an Enum class using jmockt?

Tags: java, unit-testing, enums, jmockit

I am trying to write unit test for my below old legacy enum class. The method which I am trying to unit test is - `toLocalPookString`.

Whenever I am running my unit test code, it is always going inside the `if statement` in `toLocalPookString` method since `this` is always getting resolved to `CORP`.

```
public enum DatacenterEnum {
    CORP, PHX, SLC, LVS;

    private static final DatacenterEnum ourlocation = compareLocation();

    private static DatacenterEnum compareLocation() {
        // some code here
    }

    private String toLocalPookString() {
        if (this == CORP || !(TestUtils.getEnvironmentName().equalsIgnoreCase("production"))) {
            return "/pp/dc/phx";
        }

        return "/pp/dc/" + name().toLowerCase();
    }


    public static final String BETA_POOK_STRING = ourlocation.toLocalPookString();

}
```

Is there any way I can mock `this` to `PHX` or `SLC` or `LVS` apart from `CORP` so that in `toLocalPookString` it should not go inside `if statement`? I am using jmockit here.

```
new MockUp<TestUtils>() {
    @Mock
    public String getEnvironmentName() {
    return "production";
    }
};

String ss = DatacenterEnum.BETA_POOK_STRING;
System.out.println(ss);
```

It is  pretty simple but somehow I am not able to understand how to do it? Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm confused, but it may have just been a long day. Can you clarify something? If you're unit-testing `toLocalPookString`, why do you want to mock `this`? Isn't `this` your SUT?

Comment: @Lilshieste: It's been a long day for me I guess as well. But in short, I need to mock `toLocalPookString` such that it don't go into if block.

Comment: I think I'm just unclear on what you're testing. Why is `this == CORP` if that's not what you're trying to test? (I think the details of the `compareLocation` function would be helpful.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you *could* easily mock the enum, as follows:

```
new MockUp<DatacenterEnum>() {
    @Mock DatacenterEnum compareLocation() { return DatacenterEnum.LVS; }
};
```

However, because the JVM can only perform static initialization *once* for a given class/enum, the test would only work if the enum hadn't yet been loaded and initialized.
So, a more robust test would be the following.

```
@Test
public void whenDatacenterIsNotCORPThenLocalPookStringShouldIncludeEnumName() {
    new MockUp<TestUtils>() {
        @Mock String getEnvironmentName() { return "production"; }
    };

    DatacenterEnum notCORP = DatacenterEnum.LVS;
    String ss = Deencapsulation.invoke(notCORP, "toLocalPookString");

    assertTrue(ss.toUpperCase().endsWith(notCORP.name()));
}
```

This works, but note that writing separate tests for `private` methods is generally considered bad form. Ideally, tests should call public methods which would indirectly exercise the private ones. In this particular case, however, there is no such public method, so I guess it's acceptable.